# SSIS - Search string - Script task

Tags: c#, ssis

I'd like to know if it's possible to input a query result as an array using a script task(C#)?  I found a code that uses a script task but does not assing each value of a query result in a variable.

```
//Read list of Tables with Schema from Database
string query = "Select * From "+TableName;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
//myADONETConnection.Open();

DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
myADONETConnection.Close();



string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder +"\\"+ FileNamePart +"_" + datetime + FileExtension;

StreamWriter sw = null;
sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

// Write the Header Row to File
int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;

for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
{
   sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
   if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
   {
      sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
   }
}
sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

// Write All Rows to the File
foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
{
   for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
   {
       if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
       {
           sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
       }
       if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
       {
           sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
       }
    }
       sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by array?  You have TableName but what is that and where is it coming from?  That is not a variable name/value.  Is that going to be dynamic/change.  What is your end result you are looking for?  To output your entire table structure to a file?

Comment: Basically, I'll make a query that returns multiple columns and rows and I'd like to assign each data in a variable, like a Foreach loop container. This code is an example.

Comment: In your example your writing to a file not variables.  Why would you want/need to save the data to variables/what purpose/need is this for?  Also if you wanted to do something like this an array would not work, you would need an object/datatable.   Though the select statement does this automatically.

Comment: Because I'd like to make an automatic search in variables.

Comment: Ok, I really want to help, but I dont know what that means?  Automatic search?  Search what the tables for values in all the rows/columns of your table?  If you are doing a search or something why using SSIS?

Comment: I think if you click the edit button and provide a few sentences describing what you hope to accomplish with this, we might better understand your needs. Stated another way: what is the business problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @user2316555 is the issue solved? why ignoring the provided answer if it doesn't work leave a comment to the answerer to elaborate more else if it is working you have to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following comment:

> Basically, I'll make a query that returns multiple columns and rows and I'd like to assign each data in a variable, like a Foreach loop container. This code is an example

I will assume that you are looking to store a query result inside a table and loop over the result row by row and assign the columns value inside variable. Then you should use an `Execute SQL Task` to execute the query and store the ResultSet inside a variable of type `System.Object` then loop over the ResultSet *(Result Table)* using a `ForEach Loop Container` with an `ADO enumerator`.

To get a step by step guide you can refer to one of the following links:

- [Looping Through a Result Set with the ForEach Loop](http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop)
- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)